# concat aggregate mongo db driver c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have some query written in c# using mongoDb driver.

```
var project = new BsonDocument
            {
                { "Id" , "$asCompany._id"}, { "Code" , "$asCompany.Code"}, { "Name" , "$asCompany.Name"}, { "Address" , "$asCompany.Address"},
                { "ConcurrencyId" , new BsonDocument{ { "$concat", new BsonArray{  "1_3_", "$asCompany._id" } } } }
            };
```

The above statement is using as project in the below code.

```
var joinresult3 = userCollection.Aggregate()
                .Match(user => user.Id == userId)
                .Lookup("Division", "Divisions.DivisionId", "_id", "asDivisons")
                .Lookup("Company", "asDivisons.CompanyId", "_id", "asCompany")
                .Project(project).ToList();
```

Ok, so the statement I wrote for projection is generating the following server side code. Which is seems to be correct.

```
{ "$project" : { "Id" : "$asCompany._id", "Code" : "$asCompany.Code", "Name" : "$asCompany.Name", "Address" : "$asCompany.Address", "ConcurrencyId" : { "$concat" : ["1_3_", "$asCompany._id"] } } }
```

But, the c# code is throwing following exception.
Command aggregate failed: $concat only supports strings, not array.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: you should add sample data to a [playground](https://mongoplayground.net) and share the link in your question so ppl can play with it to come up with a solution.